# converting matrix into key-value pair in BigQuery view

Tags: sql, view, google-bigquery

I have a table in Bigquery with below format and I want to get the output as a key value pair table.
Input BigQuery Table

| Attribute | Name | ID | Phone |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | row1 | 12 | 1234 |
| Second | row2 | 13 | 4567 |

The output should be as below

| ID | key | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | First_Name | row1 |
| 12 | First_Phone | 1234 |
| 13 | Second_Name | row2 |
| 13 | Second_Phone | 4567 |

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select ID, concat(Attribute, '_', col) as key, value
from `project.dataset.table`
unpivot (value for col in (Name, Phone))
```

If applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: consider voting up the answer if it helped :o)

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use arrays to unnest the values:

```
with t as (
    select 'first' as Attribute, 'row1' as Name, 12 as ID, '1234' as Phone
)
select t.id, a.key, a.value
from t cross join
     unnest(array[struct('Attribute' as key, t.attribute as value),
                  struct('Name', t.name),
                  struct('phone', t.phone)
                 ]
           ) a
```